How do I seed the creation of one or more users in OnModelCreating() with Migrations in ASP.NET MVC?
Suppose I have a standard WebApplication persisting data to a remote database. By separation of logic I have a DataAccess class, which is currently initializing a set of custom roles within OnModelCreating().
In the same method I would like to seed users and assign them roles to keep the seeding separated by logic. Currently OnModelCreating() looks like this (adding simple roles):
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

    
    modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityRole>().HasData(
    new IdentityRole
    {
        Id = "300c6b87-3d71-407c-8379-53e4b3091a8d",
        Name = "Administrator",
        NormalizedName = "Administrator".ToUpper(),
        ConcurrencyStamp = null

    });
    //More roles added here
}

What is the standard and best practice approach of doing so given properties like Id, and the other array of properties, are usually generated by the database?

You are on the right track, adding roles is done through OnModelCreating(), but you shouldn't specify the Id's as they are generated on the fly with the Guid struct. If you specify them directly it might lose uniqueness. In terms of adding roles your code is also correct, but I would remove the unnecessary ConcurrencyStamp declaration as it is null by default.
Here is my way of doing it, copied it from Teddy Smith :
EDIT
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(builder);

    List<IdentityRole> roles = new List<IdentityRole>
    {
        new IdentityRole
        {
            Name = "Admin",
            NormalizedName = "ADMIN"
        },
        new IdentityRole
        {
            Name = "User",
            NormalizedName = "USER"
        },
        new IdentityRole
        {
            Name = "Super-User",
            NormalizedName = "SUPER-USER"
        }
    };
    builder.Entity<IdentityRole>().HasData(roles);

    var hasher = new PasswordHasher<IdentityUser>();
    List<IdentityUser> users = new List<IdentityUser>
    {
        new IdentityUser
        {
            UserName = "adminuser",
            Email = "admin@example.com",
            NormalizedUserName = "ADMINUSER",
            NormalizedEmail = "ADMIN@EXAMPLE.COM",
            PasswordHash = hasher.HashPassword(null, "AdminPassword123!"),
            EmailConfirmed = true,
        },
    };
    builder.Entity<IdentityUser>().HasData(users);

    List<IdentityUserRole<string>> userRoles = new List<IdentityUserRole<string>>
    {
        new IdentityUserRole<string>
        {
            RoleId = roles.First(r => r.Name == "Admin").Id,
            UserId = users.First(u => u.UserName == "adminuser").Id
        },
    };
    builder.Entity<IdentityUserRole<string>>().HasData(userRoles);
}


Seeded User

User Roles


I also simply copied the current values and optimally I would go with using a randomizer - I just added pre-defined values since I have read somewhere all properties or fields need to be initialized explicitly in the OnModelCreating(). The Roles are also quite simply, but we're having seeds with lost of more fields when adding user rows and these are the ones, which I am confused about. So what you're saying is I don't need to initialize all values generated by GUID? Which ones are these for Identity users?

Ok, if you're having more fields in your user you just need to create an  AppUser Class which has your properties(Like LastName, FirstName, isSubscribed, etc.)(No need to define Guid here, it comes with the base class), then perform the migration and finally the database update. Then when you will create the user(In most cases its a sign up page) you will take the request, create the user with your AppUser class and then add it to the AspNetUsers table with userManager.CreateAsync(appUser, password). Consider checking out the video I linked above, it explains it all in great detail.

After you've created the user, you need to check whether the creation has been successful with createdUser.Succeeded and then add them to the specified role with userManager.AddToRoleAsync(appUser, "YourRoleHere")

Are you sure about this needed to be done when seeding the data directly as a part of Migrations? This is the typical way to go through the standard Identity implementation when the WebApplication is active, no?

Sorry, I thought you only had roles, I updated my answer, here you can specify the role and the user and with the IdentityUserRole you can assign the roles directly in OnModelCreating()
